# Fin-hypergrid.js in Chrome errors when setting showRowNumbers = false

Tags: javascript, openfin

Title says it, when I set property `showRowNumbers = false` I get thousands of these errors; when I comment it out no errors but the column with row-number and checkbox will display (which I am trying to turn off).

For example in the HTML:

`<script src="https://openfin.github.io/fin-hypergrid/build/fin-hypergrid.js"></script>
<div id="fin-grid"></div>`

Then in javascript:

```
var hg = new fin.Hypergrid('#fin-grid',
{
    data: [ { foo : 0.0 , bar : 0.0 , bat : 0.0 } ],
});
// Uncommenting this causes thousands of errors
//hg.properties.showRowNumbers = false;
```

Here's the full error/stack trace:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'visibleColumn' of undefined
    at Constructor.<anonymous> (https://openfin.github.io/fin-hypergrid/build/fin-hypergrid.js:21121:23)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Array.value (https://openfin.github.io/fin-hypergrid/build/fin-hypergrid.js:21510:48)
    at Constructor.paintCellsByColumnsAndRows (https://openfin.github.io/fin-hypergrid/build/fin-hypergrid.    js:21118:25)
    at Constructor.renderGrid (https://openfin.github.io/fin-hypergrid/build/fin-hypergrid.js:22206:38)
    at Constructor.paint (https://openfin.github.io/fin-hypergrid/build/fin-hypergrid.js:21927:18)
    at Canvas.paintNow (https://openfin.github.io/fin-hypergrid/build/fin-hypergrid.js:16190:28)
    at Canvas.tickPaint (https://openfin.github.io/fin-hypergrid/build/fin-hypergrid.js:16076:18)
    at Canvas.tickPainter (https://openfin.github.io/fin-hypergrid/build/fin-hypergrid.js:16094:18)
    at https://openfin.github.io/fin-hypergrid/build/fin-hypergrid.js:16552:27
```

Any pointers appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One of the maintainers of Hypergrid here! We are managing this ticket in github here: https://github.com/openfin/fin-hypergrid/issues/594. We'll be sure to look into this asap and update you and this thread. Thanks for the heads up!